# How to define user and group being unique together in django

Tags: django

How to define user and group being unique together in django?

Comment: Before you ask a question your are expected to try out it yourself. You should have done your research and you should be able to submit your findings here and state what worked and what not. Then only members of SO be able to suggest alterations and improvement. You cannot expect members of SO to write code for you. Learn [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in your question: `unique_together`.

Here is a reference to the official documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together

Example:

```
unique_together('user', 'group)
```

Assuming that `user` and `group` are referencing to other models, this should be set in the model (db table) that connects both models, conventionally called something like `yourapp_user_group`.

Comment: but that is a problem with default auth_user and auth_group , how to apply unique_together with this model

Comment: @ductx Please read, and if needed, reread the comment below your question. Then revise your question and explain exactly your problem, ideally provide some code you have tried. Unfortunately I can't read thoughts and don't have a crystall ball, so provided an answer to your initial question. The problem you describe in your comment can be eventually solved with defining custom user and group models, which inherit from the django models.